# Only one jQuery click event for div with same class name

Tags: jquery

There are two `div` sections with the same class and also has same `ul` and `li` and `a`.

I have two jQuery click events in my code. When I click Google both of the jQuery click events fire. But I do not want both to do so, only one. How do I achieve this?

For example, if Google gets clicked I want only that jQuery click event to do something, not the other one. These are the DOM element I am working with:

```
<div class = "abc">
 <ul>  
  <li class="year_"><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class ="abc">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="www.yahoo.com>yahoo</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The `href` might change so I cannot base my selector on that. The code that I have follows.

```
$( 'div.abc ul li[class^="year_"]  a' ).click( function(){
    //do something
});

$( 'div.abc ul li a' ).click( function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: You could just add an unique ID to each link, it'd make reading those selectors much easier IMO.

Comment: Does `ul. ` actually work? That seems to be a bit odd...

Comment: I'm sure jQuery's [`$.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) or [`$.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) could come in handy, including maybe even with just one handler...

Comment: ul. is a mistake I removed it from the question. it should have been just ul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a conditional statement, finding the li with the "year_" class:

```
$( 'div.abc ul li a' ).click( function(){
    if ($(this).parents('li').is('[class^="year_"]')){
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/cV3Fz/).

Comment: This is the appropriate way to tackle the question. +1

Comment: I agree (see comment above): http://jsfiddle.net/EFkUp/ (And I did see the edit... `;)`)

Comment: The stray `ul.` period selector should be removed from the example code, as well.